# Crop image in four

Tags: python, opencv

The cropped images are shown with `cv2.imshow` but you can not save them with cv2.imwrite

I tried if it is a problem with the input variables with the output variables with type and they all gave numpy.ndarray

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def recotar_imagen(gray):
    #Read the image
    gray = cv2.imread('imagengris.jpg')
    print type (gray)

    #Means of the image within a matrix
    heigth, width = gray.shape[:2]
    n = width
    h = heigth
    x = 0
    y = 0

    #Formulas for half of the image in x y
    x2 = int(round ((n-1)/2)) 
    y2 = int(round ((h-1)/2))
    x3 =  x2 + 1
    y3 =  y2 + 1

    #Operator for the first image 
    #cropped_lu is for the image on the left above
    cropped_lu = gray[x:x2, y:y2]
    print type (cropped_lu)
    cv2.imshow("cropped_lu.jpg", cropped_lu)
    cv2.imwriter("cropped_lu.jp", cropped_lu)

    #Operator for the second image
    #cropped_ru is for the image on the right above
    cropped_ru = gray[x3:n-1, y:y2]
    print type (cropped_ru)
    cv2.imshow("cropped_ru.jpg", cropped_ru)
    cv2.write("cropped_ru.jpg", cropped_ru)

    #Operator for the third image
    #cropped_ld is for the image on the left below
    cropped_ld = gray[x:x2, y3:h-1]
    print type (cropped_ld)
    cv2.imshow("cropped_ld.jpg", cropped_ld)
    cv2.imsave("cropped_ld.jpg", cropped_ld)


    #Operator for the fourth image 
    #cropped_ld is for the image on the right below
    cropped_rd = gray[x2:n-1, y3:h-1]
    print type (cropped_rd)
    cv2.imshow("cropped_rd.jpg", cropped_rd)
    cv2.imwrite("cropped_rd.jpg", cropped_rd)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Error log

> line 55, in recotar_imagen
>   cv2.imwriter("cropped_lu.jp", cropped_lu)
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imwriter'

Comment: Voting to close due to typos in the method that is generating the error.

Answer (score -1):

The method is `cv2.imwrite()` not `cv2.imwriter()`

Comment: I already corrected it but this error marks me error: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/imgcodecs/src/loadsave.cpp:677: error: (-2) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function imwrite_

Comment: @DiegoDelezé This is because you tried to save the image with an extension of .jp which opencv does not handle as it is not a correct extension for an image

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23207762)

Comment: @AdrianW This answer does indeed solve OPs question. OP had a typo in their code, and this answer points it out clearly. OP has other problems in the code, and they have asked it here as a comment.

Comment: @ShawnMathew No, it does not. There are additional mistakes that this answer doesn't address (The OP apparently can't write the same function call twice -- in the 4 copies of the common code block, there are 4 different calls to (mostly nonexistant) functions.). Furthermore, questions that are about typographical errors (which this definitely qualifies for, plus lack of attention to details or even  reading the doces) are off-topic here. No point answering this.

Answer (score -1):

You wanted to write `imwrite` not `imwriter`.

Comment: Doesn't catch all the other mistakes. And honestly, with 60k rep, why do you even answer this sort of blatantly off-topic question with a single sentence rather than commenting and flagging for closure?